# 4011 when going live with paypal express checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I use this URL for express checkout with paypal (in production):

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=MYTOKEN

it gives me an unpleaseant server error on paypal side. I am not sure if this is the correct URL or not or if this is a paypal error.

Instead this works very well (in testing mode):

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=MYTOKEN

Is there something I miss? paypal error page is 4011.

Comment: Can you include the SetExpressCheckout API request and response (minus your credentials) that you've used to create the token? Is the email address on the PayPal account confirmed?

Comment: Oh no. I have requested my token from the wrong endpoint. Thank you so much for reminding of this. If you would like to write an response I will mark the question as answered.

Comment: Ah, yes, that would do it as well. Glad you got it fixed. I've upvoted your comment as it contains the actual answer itself.